# How to untar a file and access all the folders and subfolders within it and create a dataframe?

Tags: python, r, database, tar

I have an email dataset. The dataset itself is 2 GB and it is downloaded as a tar.gz file. When I extract it on my system, I get a folder named "maildr".

When I go into the "maildr" folder, I have list of folders with each folder representing a user. When I click on a folder representing a user, I get more subfolders like "inbox", "sent mail", "deleted mail" etc.

Now when I click on "inbox", I have a set of text files that contain the actual email. How do I traverse through the folders and subfolders and access emails and create a relevant dataframe is the question.

Good news is I found a similar solution but that is in R and I am finding difficulty to do the same in python.

```
if (!file.exists("enron_mail_20150507.tgz")) {
    untar("enron_mail_20150507.tgz")
}

emails <- list.files("maildir/", full.names = TRUE, recursive = 
TRUE)
emails <- emails[grep("/inbox", emails)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create one dataframe for the first folder.
Then you should append all dataframes to the first folder.

In order to create one dataframe for one folder, for example at the mailbox folder do:

```
# Put in your mailbox path of the current user where the text files are saved
mypath = "home/archid/..../mailbox"
setwd(mypath)

# Create list of text files
txt_files_ls = list.files(path=mypath, pattern="*.txt") 
# Read the files in, assuming comma separator
txt_files_df <- lapply(txt_files_ls, function(x) {read.table(file = x, header = T, sep =",")})
# Combine them
combined_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(txt_files_df, as.data.frame))
```

Then you need to read all folders and append to the first dataframe. You will need a for loop and the append command: pandas.DataFrame.append.

One other approach is to make a bash script that will read each folder and it will create one *.csv file for each folder. Then you will merge all csv files. Check the csv write to file commands.